# robots.txt for subdomain iis7

Tags: iis-7, robots.txt

I have two different sites in iis7
both point to the same folder
they have different subdomains

www.sitename.com
foo.sitename.com

they are essentially the same website, but it runs different logic depending on the subdomain.

i want www.sitename.com to be indexed on google (it already is)
but I dont want foo.sitename.com to ever be searchable.

can i exclude it withe a robot file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are they sharing the same physical folder?  The only workaround I can think of using if so is using urlrewrite to block those types of requests to foo.somedomain.com.  Otherwise using two separate folders and two robots.txt files is another method.  The robots.txt is only as good as the search engine if it honors it or not.

Edit one other method would be putting the subdomain below the root domain and using url rewrite to redirect requests to it.

http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2010/01/26/iis-url-rewrite-hosting-multiple-domains-under-one-site.aspx